# Create class to extract month and time delta in DataFrame using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, class

I am new to Python and in learning process, got a question to create a class to extract month value and time delta in DataFrame.

Data:

```
                  time_1                 time_2
0   2017-06-27 16:53:42 2017-06-27 20:05:36
1   2018-12-10 07:06:56 2018-12-10 11:43:29
2   2018-10-04 18:45:29 2018-10-04 23:20:38
3   2018-10-03 08:03:36 2018-10-03 10:56:40
4   2018-07-20 09:27:34 2018-07-20 13:48:30
5   2017-08-06 14:23:51 2017-08-06 19:20:46
6   2018-03-19 10:47:24 2018-03-19 12:12:49
7   2018-09-14 10:32:44 2018-09-14 13:14:49
8   2018-08-15 06:06:40 2018-08-15 10:15:31
9   2018-03-04 02:13:01 2018-03-04 03:23:59

Function to extract month:
df['time_1'].dt.month

Function to calculate delta:
(df['time_2']-df['time_1']).dt.total_seconds()
```

In this case, I can provide random amount of rows of DataFrame as input to extract outputs above. I studied class examples and tried to achieve this, but not succeeded. Can anyone please help me on this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what exactly you are looking for but assuming that you want either to create class functions/variables for your data frame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class foo():# creating your class

    def __init__(self,df): #important part of class. 
        self.df = df #storing the value assigned
        self.month = self.df['a'] #class variables 
        self.delta = self.df['b']-self.df['a']
    def month1(self): #class functions
        return self.df['a']
    def delta1(self):
        return self.df['b']-self.df['a']

if __name__ == '__main__': #Basic template for python
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) #Simplified example


    x = foo(df2)
    print(x.month1()) #class function example
    print(x.delta1())
    print(x.month) #class variable
    print(x.delta)
```